# How can use 'AS' syntax?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to different data in different table I am trying use AS 
I try all code all of them work but one by one , ı am not working together
I try two ways but ıts nor working  ı thought roung syntax ı resarch but ı am new in sql

My first way:

```
            string cmd = @" SELECT COUNT(Ref) AS data,"; 
        cmd += @" (select count(CustomerID) as data2 from Contract where DATEDIFF(DAY,StartDate,GETDATE()) between 0 and 30),";
        cmd += @" (select count(distinct(CustomerID)) as data3 from Contract where FinishDate > GETDATE()),";
        cmd += @" (select count(Ref) as data4 from Support where DATEDIFF(DAY,StartDate,GETDATE()) between 0 and 30)";
        cmd += @" FROM Customer WHERE (Deleted = 0 or Deleted is null) ";
```

My second way:

```
    string cmd = @" SELECT COUNT(Ref) ,"; 
        cmd += @" (select count(CustomerID) from Contract where DATEDIFF(DAY,StartDate,GETDATE()) between 0 and 30) as data2 ,";
        cmd += @" (select count(distinct(CustomerID))  from Contract where FinishDate > GETDATE()) as data3,";
        cmd += @" (select count(Ref)  from Support where DATEDIFF(DAY,StartDate,GETDATE()) between 0 and 30) as data4";
        cmd += @" FROM Customer WHERE (Deleted = 0 or Deleted is null) AS data ";
```

Comment: What is not working? Is there an error message? What is the expected result? Can you show us the table structure.

Comment: 'AS'  syntax error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alias must be assigned at a query level, not in subquery (1st variant).

WHERE condition cannot have an alias (2nd variant).

```
SELECT COUNT(Ref) AS data, 
       ( select count(CustomerID)
         from Contract 
         where DATEDIFF(DAY,StartDate,GETDATE()) between 0 and 30) as data2 , 
       ( select count(distinct(CustomerID))
         from Contract 
         where FinishDate > GETDATE()) as data3, 
       ( select count(Ref) 
         from Support 
         where DATEDIFF(DAY,StartDate,GETDATE()) between 0 and 30)  as data4
FROM Customer 
WHERE (Deleted = 0 or Deleted is null)
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me :)  I understand this code is working now

Comment: @FurkanYılmaz You have used SQL Server syntax - I have stored this. In MySQL `DATEDIFF(DAY,StartDate,GETDATE())` must be replaced with `DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, StartDate)`.

Comment: @FurkanYılmaz .. but I'd recomment to replace `DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, StartDate) between 0 and 30` with `StartDate BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND CURRENT_DATE`. It allows to use the index by `StartDate` if exists.